# Something like MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) for .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: .net, plugins, mef

I used MEF in own of my projects and I liked it a lot. It was easy and after figuring our *awkward* API model, it just worked.

Now I need something like that for .NET Framework 2.0. Is there any similar project out there which can work under .NET Framework 2.0?

I'm simply looking for adding plug-in support to my project in a simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Mono.Addins](http://mono-project.com/Mono.Addins) AFAIK its built upon .NET 2.0.

Comment: *Shameless Plug* I've started a series of posts on my blog describing my experiences using Mono.Addins in a commercial .NET application. http://codeelegance.blogspot.com

Answer (score 2):

You can try [R.SAT](http://rsat.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I know SharpDevelop has a plug-in mechanism. Maybe you could check out their source code: http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing is the System.Addins namespace but that is a 3.5 feature.  It doesn't require a different CLR than 2.0 but it does require the 3.5 framework be installed on the target machine.

http://www.codeplex.com/clraddins